# Strapi v4 use MySql Database in Production

Tags: mysql, strapi

How to add configuration that Strapi use mysql in production and sqlite for local development?

Strapi v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add mysql driver `yarn add mysql` or `npm install mysql`
2. Add dotenv `yarn add dotenv` or `npm install dotenv`
3. Create new file: `config/env/production/database.js`
4. Add the following content:

> ```
> module.exports = ({ env }) => ({   connection: {
>  client: "mysql",
>  connection: {
>    host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
>    port: env("DATABASE_PORT", 3306),
>    database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "default"),
>    user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "root"),
>    password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", ""),
>  },
>  useNullAsDefault: true,   
>  }, 
> });
> ```

5. Add your config to the .env File in Production.
6. Strapi will pick the correct configuration.

Answer (score 1):

1.Add MySQL driver npm install mysql

2.Add sqlite3 driver npm install sqlite3

3.Set you environment file we do it like this

```
3.1.    On dev set ENV_PATH=%CD%\..\environment\%USERNAME%-s4.env

3.2.    On server export ENV_PATH=/home/ec2-user/backend/environment/prod.env
```

4. Set DB_DRIVER in env file to either mysql or sqlite3
   5.Amend your database config file:

   ```
           module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
               connection:env("DB_DRIVER", "mysql")==="mysql"?{
                   client: 'mysql',
                   connection:{
                          host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "localhost"),
                          port: env("DATABASE_PORT", 3306),
                          database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "default"),
                          username: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "root"),
                          password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", ""),
                     }
                   }
               :{
                   client: 'sqlite',
                   connection: {
                     filename: path.join(__dirname, '..', env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/data.db')),
                   },
                   useNullAsDefault: true,
               },
           });
   ```